# Java project output differs from debug output

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-construction

I'm writing a toy compiler in Java. My IDE is IntelliJ IDEA. Now, I want to print a `.s` file, but I found that:

If I run the project, it prints

```
.block0_3:
    addi %18, zero, 0
    mv %0, %18
    j .block0_5
.block0_4:
    la %20, .str.1
    mv a0, %20
    call print
    j .block0_3
```

If I use the debug mode, it prints

```
.block0_3:
    la %18, .str.1
    mv a0, %18
    call print
    j .block0_4
.block0_4:
    addi %19, zero, 0
    mv %0, %19
    j .block0_5
```

In brief, the two output should be the same. Is there any idea?

Give me some advice to solve the problem.

Comment: Looks like the two blocks are simply swapped (with some added difference in local variable numbering). Is it possible that you simply have some random order effects by using structures like `HashMap` or `HashSet` which leads to non-reproducible output order? If that's the case then the debug/run distinction would be red herring.

Comment: Yes, the block is stored as `HashSet`. So it's due to the `Hash` function? And I can solve this by a normal `Set`?

Comment: If you want the order of items in a `Set` (that's currently a `HashSet`) to stay consistent but don't particularly care which order, then replacing the `HashSet` with a `LinkedHashSet` is probably the simplest change to achieve that. Similarly `HashMap` -> `LinkedHashMap` does the same for maps. Generally speaking having reproducible compilation (i.e. same input always produces the same output) is not strictly necessary, but very useful for debugging.